# Width equal to content

Tags: css, width

I'm experiencing some trouble with the width property of CSS. I have some paragraphs inside a div. I'd like to make the width of the paragraphs equal to their content, so that their green background looks like a label for the text. What I get instead is that the paragraphs inherit the width of the div father node which is wider.

```css
#container {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#container p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Sample Text 1</p>
  <p>Sample Text 2</p>
  <p>Sample Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

By default `p` tags are `block` elements, which means they take 100% of the parent `width`.

You can change their display property with:

```
#container p {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

But it puts the elements side by side.

To keep each element on its own line you can use:

```
#container p {
   clear:both;
   float:left;
}
```

<sub>(If you use float and need to clear after floated elements, see this link for different techniques: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)</sub>

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/CvJ3W/5/**

**Edit**

If you go for the solution with `display:inline-block` but want to keep each item in one line, you can just add a `<br>` tag after each one:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>Sample Text 1</p><br/>
  <p>Sample Text 2</p><br/>
  <p>Sample Text 3</p><br/>
</div>
```

New demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/CvJ3W/7/**

Comment: Seeing the new edit, I respectfully disagree with throwing ```<br>``` for styling.

Comment: @VisWebsoft I agree with you you always have the option to use ´float´ to keep each element in new lines. But give always all the possible solutions is nice, just choice the one of your preference.

Answer (score 219):

I set width as max-content and it worked for me.

`width: max-content;`

Comment: Not supported by IE or Edge though

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content Agree with @pkr298 Just use for 'fun' stuff - not production.

Comment: Also, the component will have the width set, and if the browser window is less than that, it will not adjust.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Simple and crisp.

Comment: @NachoColoma i now use `max-width: max-content;` and that brings back the responsive behavior of the container element.

Comment: @pkr298 That's no longer the case for Edge according to https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content.

Answer (score 14):

The solution with `inline-block` forces you to insert `<br>` after each element.
The solution with `float` forces you to wrap all elements with "clearfix" div.

Another elegant solution is to use `display: table` for elements.

With this solution you don't need to insert line breaks manually (like with `inline-block`), you don't need a wrapper around your elements (like with floats) and you can center your element if you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/8md3jy4r/3/

Answer (score 11):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to the `p` styling should take of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/pyq3C/

```
#container p{
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It partially works now. The width of the paragraphs equal the content as I wanted. The problem is that now I get all the paragraphs in just a line instead of three.

Comment: You can force to the next line by adding: `float: left; clear: left;`

Comment: Adding `float: left` to an element displayed as `inline-block` will set it to `block` according to CSS 2.1 REC ([relationships between display, position, and float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)) so you can as well remove `inline-block` and it won't change anything

Answer (score 10):

set width attribute as: width: fit-content

`demo:` http://jsfiddle.net/rvrjp7/pyq3C/114

Answer (score 7):

**Using** `display:inline-block;` **will not work** for long sentences without spaces like `HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood...etc` to fix this consider using `word-wrap: break-word;` instead

it's made to allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line., also **Facebook** using it

**Example**

```css
#container {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
#container p{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
}

#wrap {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
#wrap p{
   word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1> display:inline-block;</h1>
<div class='flex'>

<div id="container">
<h5>With spaces </h5>
    <p>Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <h5>No specaes (not working )</h5>  <p>HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood</p>
</div>
</div>




<h1>  word-wrap: break-word;</h1>
<div class='flex'>

<div id="wrap">
<h5>With spaces </h5>
    <p>Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
  <h5>No specaes (working )</h5>  <p>HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `display:inline-block` and then adjust your margins.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2MrC/

Answer (score 5):

You can use either of below :-

1) display : inline-block :

http://jsbin.com/feneni/edit?html,css,js,output

Uncomment the line

```
 float:left;
 clear:both
```

and you will find that parent container has collapsed.

2) Using display : table

http://jsbin.com/dujowep/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 5):

You can use flex to achieve this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

`flex-start` will automatically adjust the width of children to their contents.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `<span>` element instead. Or if you prefer, try `display:inline`

Comment: It partially works now. The width of the paragraphs equal the content as I wanted. The problem is that now I get all the paragraphs in just a line instead of three.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `display: flex` for whatever reason and need on browsers like Edge/IE, you can instead use:

> display: inline-flex

[With ~97% browser support for inline-flex.](https://caniuse.com/#search=inline-flex)

Answer (score 0):

Despite using `display: inline-block`. My div would fill the screen width when the children elements had their widths set to `%` of parent. If anyone else is looking for a solution to this and doesn't mind using screen proportion instead of parent proportion, replace the `%` with `vw` for width (Viewport Width), or `vh` for height (Viewport Height).

Answer (score -1):

just use  display: table; on your case.

Comment: Please make your answer better by explaining why `display: table` is the way to go. Look at other answers to get better idea.

Answer (score -2):

You can use CSS property like this:

```
div {
    display: inherit;
}
```

I hope this helps.