# sizing a container based on the content

Tags: css

The following is a screen shot of some content that is part of a form validation in website project that's in the development phase:

[image]

This content is currently contained in a div that specifies the width to be 20%.  Prior to adding that rule the div stretched horizontally across the entire screen which looked excessive for the short messages that are contained within.  Is there a way to let the div (or some other appropriate container) automatically adjust its width to be just wide enough for the content it contains?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: set width equal to content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383622/css-set-width-equal-to-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `display: inline-block` or `float`.
Here is the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdICu/