# How to set width of a p tag according to the width of a h tag

Tags: html, css, width

So I have a `<h>` tag and a `<p>` tag. The width of `<p>` tag needs to follow the width of `<h>` tag and the width of `<h>` tag will be altered dynamically according to the length of its text.

Below are examples

```
Example1:

Heading: this text will change from time to time

Paragraph: Width of this text needs to fit the 
width of previous Heading tag. blah blah blah bl
ah blah blah lbah

Example2:

Heading: this text changed
Paragraph: Width of this 
text also changed because
width of prevous heading
changed.
```

I cannot use javascript so will need a css or html solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: Please kindly check out this link: [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383622/css-set-width-equal-to-content)

Comment: I think its more accurately to help you if you included your existing html and css. So their answer will use your example instead of making theirs.

Comment: @Michael Thanks buddy but my question addresses a different issue.

Comment: @bot You are right, should do that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do it with CSS table + table-caption.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhLnehfm/)**

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.container h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
.container p {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Short Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec risus dignissim, varius nibh sed, dapibus tortor.</p>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Long Long Long Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec risus dignissim, varius nibh sed, dapibus tortor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, what does the `display: table-caption;` do that any other don't?

Comment: @LGSon It's often being used for making image caption width to match image width. The caption element (or css table caption) takes part in the table model. You can read more from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element).