# how to use margin:0 auto without setting width of inner div

Tags: html, css

I tried setting width to auto but that didn't work either.

```html
<div style='width:100%;background-color:lightblue;text-align:center'>
test
<div style='margin:0 auto;background-color:blue;'>
new test
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: This would center the div, but it is not possible without specifying width, there are endless possibilities. You can set margin left and right to some value though, it will be centered if they are the same.

Comment: I would like the inner div to have a width equal to the width of the space taken up for the characters 'new test' but I now understand the problem.  I suppose we could calculate the length of the text and set width to that

Comment: @DCR this question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383622/css-set-width-equal-to-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `inline` or `inline-block`

```html
<div style='width:100%;background-color:lightblue;text-align:center'>
test<br>
<div style='margin:0 auto;display:inline;background-color:blue;'>
new test
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wrong, it is not the "display:inline" this is making this centered, it is the "text-align:center" of the parent div that is doing so.  Remove the text-align:center and you will see both elements left justify.  Replace display:inline with "width:100px;" and "new test" will pop back to the center.

Comment: correct `margin: 0 auto` may not needed but if you set width or remove `display:inline` the child will not have width to auto