# How do I get the exact width of the inner text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: A part of my project]

Hi, I need to know the exact width of the inner text in CSS. As you can see in the image, I want those menu items to have a proper width respectively, not including paddings or margins, so that I can give them a hover effect like "Posts" item. Is there any method I can use to get the width of the inner text?

```css
/* Basic settings */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,700&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .3s;
    color: #333;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Main */
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
header > div {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header > #logo {
    width: 15%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
header > #logo img {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
}
header > #search {
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
header > #search input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
header > #search a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
}
header > #search > #search-box {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header > #gnb {
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
}
header > #gnb ul {
    margin: 0 30px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
header > #gnb li {
    display: inline-block;
}
header > #gnb li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
header > #gnb a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
header > #gnb a:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.premium {
    color: orangered;
}
#social-media-icons {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
    height: 70px;
}
#social-media-icons ul {
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
#social-media-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#social-media-icons li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#social-media-icons li a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
#social-media-icons li a:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
#profile {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#profile a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#profile a img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#sub-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
#sub-header ul {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#sub-header li {
    line-height: 47px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#sub-header li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid cornflowerblue !important;
}
#sub-header a {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.selected {
    border-bottom: 3px solid cornflowerblue !important;
}
main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
aside {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
#bill-gates {
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
#bill-gates-image {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#bill-gates-image > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#bill-gates-bio {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#bill-gates-bio > h2 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#bill-gates-bio > p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#bill-gates-bio > p:last-child {
    color: #CCC;
}
#bill-gates-follow-button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#bill-gates-follow-button > a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#bill-gates-follow-button > a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(70, 134, 253);
}
#bill-gates-connect-button {
    text-align: center;
}
#bill-gates-connect-button > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background-color: white;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#bill-gates-connect-button > a:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
#aside-middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    height: 80px;
}
#connections {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
}
#followers {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Bill Gates</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="LinkedIn logo">
            </a>
        </div><!--
     --><div id="search">
            <div id="search-box">
                <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search"><!--
             --><a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div><!--
        --><div id="gnb">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Connections</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Interest</a>
                </li>
                <li class="premium">
                    <a href="#">Try Premium</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--
        --><div id="social-media-icons">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">➕</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--
        --><div id="profile">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="./img/avatar.jpg" alt="Profile image">
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="sub-header">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="#">Posts</a>
            </li><li>
                <a href="#">Background</a>
            </li><li>
                <a href="#">Recommendations</a>
            </li><li>
                <a href="#">Following</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <main>
        <aside>
            <div id="bill-gates">
                <div id="bill-gates-image">
                    <img src="./img/bill-gates-avatar.png" alt="Bill Gates Profile image">
                </div>
                <div id="bill-gates-bio">
                    <h2>Bill Gates</h2>
                    <p>Microsoft Founder</p>
                    <p>Greater Seattle Area</p>
                </div>
                <div id="bill-gates-follow-button">
                    <a href="#">Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="bill-gates-connect-button">
                    <a href="#">Connect ↓</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="aside-middle">
                <div id="connections">
                    <h3>200</h3>
                    <p>connections</p>
                </div>
                <div id="followers">
                    <h3>1.9M</h3>
                    <p>followers</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your question: [Width equal to content.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383622/width-equal-to-content)

Comment: Thanks. But rather than getting the exact width of the inner text itself, I'd like to give it an extra width by 10px on both sides.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap text with span tag? In your current structure?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there any good method using span tag?

Comment: Can you please share your code in the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `width` property of an element, which gets the width of the content area excluding any paddings, borders or margins.

```css
.bg-tag {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bg-tag:focus {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000; #change colour as you like
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="bg-tag">Background</a>
```