# How to adjust div width with the siz of text inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

My idea is to make each element within `div`s that have the `.main_content` class, to have a width equal to the width of the text inside it. How do I this?

As you can see, the width of each one (`span`, `h2,` `p` and `h6`) is the same as the `.main_content` `div`. The red border demonstrates this.

So, how do I make the width of each div fit the text within those divs? (*With only CSS*)

```css
.main_content {
   width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.main_content > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
       <span class="growth">Growth</span>
       <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
       <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
       </p>
       <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P: I've been trying to manually set the size of `width` of each element. But there is too much code. Is there any clever way to to this?

Comment: `display:table`  and the [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable) is wide

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37353025/8620333 .. display:table is the way to go here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 1 CSS function: `width: fit-content`
Note here: It doesnt work in IE.
Try it out:

```css
.main_content {
   width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;

}

.main_content > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
       <span class="growth">Growth</span>
       <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
       <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
       </p>
       <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love it, love it!! Many thanks!  Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Laura no problem, an accepted answer would be great

Comment: I didnt know about this fit-content. Is it new?

Comment: Will not work in some browsers (notably Firefox) without a prefix: https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content

Comment: @Laura it came out somewhere with the `grid` in 2017, but i am not sure, somebody correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @LáďaDurchánek i added an prefix

Answer (score 3):

You can try with below css and see if it works.

```css
.main_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.main_content>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
      <span class="growth">Growth</span>
      <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
      <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
      </p>
      <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS okay with IE and It even includes IE8 ....

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox on `.main_content`:

```css
.main_content {
   width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.main_content > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
       <span class="growth">Growth</span>
       <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
       <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
       </p>
       <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
width: max-content;
```

for all the child elements and this will set the with for of each one (`span`, `h2`, `p` and `h6`) width of the text inside it.

```css
.main_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.main_content>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center; 
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
      <span class="growth">Growth</span>
      <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
      <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
      </p>
      <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be fine with a `max-width:100%;` to be alike `fit-content` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

add `width: max-content` to your `.main_content > * {`.

```css
.main_content {
   width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.main_content > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_article">
  <div class="first_content">
    <div class="main_content">
       <span class="growth">Growth</span>
       <h2>5 compelling user referral campaign examples</h2>
       <p>Jumpstarts your user referral engine with these 5 approaches toreferral campaigns from popular apps.
       </p>
       <h6>Author</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be fine with a `max-width:100%;` to be alike `fit-content` somehow.